# std::runtime_error calls std::terminate but hangs

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

The following code just hangs without returning control to the shell, printing only the following message:
"terminate called after throwing an instance of std::runtime_error"

```
#include <stdexcept>
int main() { throw std::runtime_error("exception"); return 0; }
```

Why doesn't this abort the process and return control to the shell?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/4iuO69). Are you sure you're understanding your environment and are interpreting your shell correctly?

Comment: @KerrekSB, not sure what you mean, but what I mean is it is not returning me to the command prompt, classic press enter in dark space sort of thing.

Comment: What platform?  Are you running from inside an IDE? Could a debugger have intercepted the termination? Debug or release build (some platforms will try and invoke a debugger in debug build in this sort of situation)?

Comment: @RichardCritten, Fedora 23, Lenovo X1 Yoga, straight from CLI (zsh)

Comment: Running this on ubuntu works just fine. You will have to elaborate more. Specify the exact steps you're doing that leads to this situation.